# How to organize user's data in FireStore

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to create a database on Firestore that would look like this :

- Collection A (Users)
- - Document A (User 1)
- - - Data 1
- - - Data 2
- - - ThisListOfData
- - - - ThisThing1
- - - - - ThisSubData1
- - - - - ThisSubData2
- - - - ThisThing2
- - - - ...
- - Document B (User 2)

Each user have his data (username, ...). But one of his data (ThisListOfData) is a list of things (a list of activities, like yoga, sport, ...). And for each activities (ThisThing1, ...) there is subData. I want to do this like that, because the user can subscribe to more activities, delete some...

It's my first time using Firestore so I have no idea how to do that. The "ThisListOfData" should/can be a collection ? Or a data like a list of string ? If someone could help me on this one, and how to get all the "Things" inside "ThisListOfData" to check the activities the user subscribed to ?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Firestore or the Realtime Database it is more importand how you "get" the data when you try to figure out "where" and how to "structure" it.

When deciding on this always think of "where will I use this data?" and "how will I query it?".

The structure you shown us is quite OK. What I would recommend is that if there are some data parts that will be accessible also for other users to store those to a separate collection as `Users` and take a lot of effort to make the collection `Users` as secure as possible. For that reason to reduce complexity in security rules I always prefer and recommend to store such data (that should be awailable for others) into separate collections.

Also if you want to save something as data field of a document like `map` or `array` or if you want to save it as `subcollection` depends mostly on how you want to get the dat later or if you need to query on it. If you plan to run queries on it and sort such data I would recommend to save it as `collection`.

Saving data in `arrays` has some donwsides like updating that works only for the whole array.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer ! I'm having a little troubles to understand tho. In my case I have a collection "Users" and a collection "Activities". The activity one is accessible by all, it's the available activity. Now for each user I would like them to see their subscribed activity (other users cant access this), the date of subscription... How would I arrange this ?

Comment: If now and in the future only the user can see his own subscriptions you can save it under a field of the user document or a subcollection. Do you have any plans to filter on that data? How often do you need that data? Do you need it in a list of users? How much elements should it have usualy?

Comment: Hey Tarik. Regarding your last statement, that's not entirely correct. You can [update single elements within an array](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073). It's not necessary to get the whole array in order to perform an update.

Comment: Sorry what I ment is that there is no native `update` for a single element. I'm aware of such "hacks" to do it like removing and adding or doing the whole array at once. The fact there is so much explanation required to do it should be a sign to use Arrays for some data with this knowledge in mind. I would not use them for data that is updated a lot of times and has a lot of elements.